# Formula to return original value if specified character not found

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have two Excel sheets (let's say sheet1 and sheet2). For an example here, the values on sheet1 from R1C1 to R4C1 are `0(5)`, `2(6)*`, `92`and `44`.

I want to copy just the numeric values from sheet1 to sheet2. Thus, I have this formula in R1C1 of my sheet2:

```
=LEFT(Sheet1!A1,SEARCH("(",Sheet1!A1)-1)
```

This formula returns the values on sheet2 like this:

R1C1 - 0
R2C1 - 2
R3C1 - #Value!
R4C1 - #Value!

The main issue is for R3C1 and R4C1.

Can we include a logical test in the formula which returns the value `92` for R3C1 and `44` for R4C1 if the formula cannot find `"("`?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try `=IF(ISNUMBER(Sheet1!A1),Sheet1!A1,"")`

---

Only after editing the question do I now realise requirement seems to be for what may be served by a combination of OP's formula and mine above:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(Sheet1!A1),Sheet1!A1,LEFT(Sheet1!A1,SEARCH("(",Sheet1!A1)-1))
```

This will returns text as before of `0` and `2` and numbers of `92` and `44`.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can check for an error using ISERROR function:

```
=IF(ISERROR(LEFT(Sheet1!A1,SEARCH("(",Sheet1!A1)-1)),LEFT(Sheet1!A1,SEARCH("(",Sheet1!A1)-1))
```

so that is like an IF, THEN, ELSE block

IF LEFT(Sheet1!A1,SEARCH("(",Sheet1!A1)-1))= #VALUE

Then just take Sheet1!A1)-1

else take LEFT(Sheet1!A1,SEARCH("(",Sheet1!A1)-1)

that should get you started anyway

HTH

Philip